# Capture a photo and display it full size in ImageView in Android

Tags: java, android, camera, imageview

I am trying to capture a photo and display it in an ImageView. The first part is done successfully and the image is saved:

```
    public void takePhoto (View view) {
    String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String fileName = "myPhoto.jpg";
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    imageFile = new File(baseDir + File.separator + fileName);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

However, I cannot get the image displayed in full size in the ImageView:

```
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

           if (requestCode == 0)
        {
            if(imageFile.exists())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this,"file saved!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("imageFile");
                        myImage.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this,"file not saved!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
        }
}
```

The XML layout is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.trial3.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Shoot"
        android:onClick="takePhoto"/>
   
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the Manifest.XML file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.android.trial3">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String)) on the `decodeFile` method's `pathName` parameter.

> String: complete path name for the file to be decoded.

You need to pass the absolute path of your image file to `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`.

Replace the following line:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile("imageFile");
```

with:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Also, you seem to be missing the following permissions in your `Manifest.xml`:

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

So your Manifest should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.android.trial3">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

On **API level 23+** you need to request this permission at runtime.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) link out on how to request runtime permissions.